# Dynamically create a new protobuf message

Tags: c++, dynamic, protocol-buffers

Suppose I have a message A, and I want to dynamically create a new message B, and it should contain all the fields in A and one  more field (not contained in A), how to do this in protobuf?

Comment: Look into message extensions. There's no _inheritance_ mechanism in protobuf.

Answer (score 1):

First, check out the types defined in [`descriptor.h`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor). These "descriptors" describe Protobuf types. You can create one dynamically by creating a `FileDescriptorProto` (which is basically an AST for a `.proto` file; see [`descriptor.proto`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor.pb)) and then using `DescriptorPool` to "compile" it into a `FileDescriptor`. That in turn will contain a `Descriptor` for each type defined in the file.

Once you have a `Descriptor` for your dynamically-generated type, you can use [`DynamicMessage`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.dynamic_message) to dynamically construct a message object of that type. You can use the [`Reflection`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Reflection) interface to access the fields of this message dynamically.